# .insert(_:at:) not working in TextField() SwiftUI Xcode 15

Tags: swiftui, textfield, xcode15

Let's say I want to create a `TextField` for entering a credit card number. In the past, I've used `.insert(_:at:)` to add an empty space (or even a character) where I'd need it, but it looks like I'm not able to do that anymore. Unless I'm missing something? Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cardNumber: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX", text: .init(get: {
            cardNumber
        }, set: { value in
            cardNumber = ""
            
            /// Inserting space for every 4 digits
            let startIndex = value.startIndex
            for index in 0 ..< value.count {
                let stringIndex = value.index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)
                cardNumber += String(value[stringIndex])
                
                if (index + 1) % 5 == 0, value[stringIndex] != " " {
                    cardNumber.insert(" ", at: stringIndex)
                }
            }
        }))
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try making your own for matter instead of trying to intercept Binding behavior

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine helped me find the answer by using `.onChange`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var cardNumber: String = ""
  var body: some View {
    TextField("XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX", text: $cardNumber)
      .onChange(of: cardNumber, perform: { newValue in
        // Remove any existing spaces from the incoming value
        let cleanedValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        // Create a formatted version of the card number
        var formattedValue = ""
        for (index, char) in cleanedValue.enumerated() {
          formattedValue.append(char)
          if (index + 1) % 4 == 0, index < cleanedValue.count - 1 {
            formattedValue.append(" ")
          }
        }
        // Update the cardNumber property with the cleaned and formatted value
        cardNumber = formattedValue
      })
      .padding()
  }
}
```